# regex expression of getting the string after the last slash and before the question mark

Tags: regex

Example 
url = http://www.example.com/aa/bb/cc/dd?q=ab&c=1

So in this url i need to have the value dd which is after the last slash and before the question mark

how to write the regex expression for that

I have written to get the value after the last slash but could not figure out how to get the only value "dd" before query string.

Regex Expression : [^/]+$

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex expression to get the last part from the URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288812/regex-expression-to-get-the-last-part-from-the-url)

Comment: @ghoti: You're creating a circular reference. The one you linked was closed because of this one, and you're trying to close this one as a duplicate of that one. This one is the oldest, so it should remain open. The other one was properly closed as being a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

You may use below regex. This regex will match all alphabets which are followed by `?`. In your case it will be `dd`.

**EDIT** : Updated regex to use `\w` instead of just alphabets.

```
[^\/][\w]+(?=\?)
```

**Explaination**

```
[^\/] -- Do not match /
[\w]+ -- match word characters (letters, digits, underscore) 
(?=\?) -- Positive lookahead: Match alphabets(above condition) that are followed by a ?
```

Comment: +1 for the nice use of Positive lookahead to prevent the `?` from matching. But what if its `/dd9?` instead of `/dd?` ?. So I suggest you to use `\w+`  instead of `[a-z]*`

Comment: @PavanManjunath : You are correct. My intention was just to give a direction for writing regex for this particular problem. I was expecting user to tweak this to match his actual requirements. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will work, it technically gets whatever is between '/' and '?'. You may have to escape the '/', but I don't see it escaped in yours, so I left it unescaped.

`/([^/\?]+)\?`

Comment: you don't need to escape the `?` in the `[]` and you could have `(?:\?|$)` at the end (instead of `\?`) if you also want to match a URL with no ? at all.  and change `+` to `*` if you want the empty string for a URL that ends "/?".

Comment: @KKobayashi This thing works but it works for the first slash but i want the value after the last slash and before the question mark

Comment: @Prateek what language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
#(.*)/(.*)\?(.*)#
```

As I'm unsure about what language you're using, I've written this to work for PHP. It shouldn't be hard to adapt for whatever language in particular you're using.

Breakdown of the regex:

- `#` - Start and end symbol for the regex.
- `(.*)/` - Matches anything **before** the final `/` in the url.
- `(.*)\?` - Matches what's between the final `/` and before the `?`.
- Trailing `(.*)#` - Matches anything following a `?`, usually a query string.

Sure, the regex could be even shorter, but this way, you can also use the other details of the obtained URL, if you saw fit.

**EDIT**

I have used this code, with the example URL you've given:

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc/dd?q=ab&c=1";
    $regex = "#(.*)/(.*)\?(.*)#";
    preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches);
    var_dump($matches);
?>
```

This is what it returned:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc/dd?q=ab&c=1' (length=39)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc' (length=27)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string 'dd' (length=2)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string 'q=ab&c=1' (length=8)
```

As you can see, the regex works.

Comment: I am using php. But the case is i dont know how many slashes in the url it can be like this                                               http://www.abc.com/bb/cc/dd?q=ab&c=1                                 http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/dd?q=ab&c=1                                       http://www.abc.com/aa/bb/cc/dd?q=ab&c=1                                ultimately i want the value after the last slash and before the appending of query string parameters

Comment: If you always want what follows the final slash, this will work regardless.

Comment: i am using (.*)\? it is still giving me from the start of the url but not the value from the last slash

Comment: @Prateek Also, ensure that you use `(.*)/(.*)\?(.*)`, not just `(.*)\?`, else it will match _everything_ before the the `?`.

Comment: thanks for this but i missed one thing i am using php nut this regex i have to use with apache. Anyways thanks :)

Comment: If it's for apache, please put that in the tags list. It will help save future confusion. :)

Comment: Also, if this was helpful, please upvote it? And if it was what you were looking for, mark it as the correct answer? (: